# Error: Missing helper: "if_equal" handlebars

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I tried to register handlebar on my express node application, but seems like it doesn't work

```
const express = require('express');
const hbs = require('hbs');
const expressHbs = require('express-handlebars');

const app = express();
app.engine('.hbs', expressHbs({ defaultLayout: 'layout', extname: '.hbs' }));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');

hbs.registerHelper('if_equal', function(a, b, opts) {
    if (a == b) {
        return opts.fn(this)
    } else {
        return opts.inverse(this)
    }
});
```

In .hbs file I run this code

```
 {{#if_equal x "my_string"}}
       x is "my_string"
  {{else}}
       x isn't "my_string"
  {{/if_equal}}
```

Then I received this error

> Error: Missing helper: "if_equal" handlebars

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're using two different view engines. [express-handlebars](https://github.com/ericf/express-handlebars) & [hbs](https://github.com/pillarjs/hbs).

Your `.hbs` files are being rendered with `express-handlebars`, while you're registering the helper to `hbs`.

### Using hbs

Drop `express-handlebars`, and drop this line:

```
app.engine('.hbs', expressHbs({ defaultLayout: 'layout', extname: '.hbs' }));
```

The extension .hbs is the default one for [hbs](https://github.com/pillarjs/hbs#use):

> Using hbs as the default view engine requires just one line of code in
>   your app setup. This will render .hbs files when res.render is called.

```
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');

hbs.registerHelper('if_equal', function(a, b, opts) {
    if (a == b) {
        return opts.fn(this)
    } else {
        return opts.inverse(this)
    }
});
```

### Using express-handlebars

```
//remove require('hbs');
const expressHbs = require('express-handlebars');

const hbs = expressHbs.create({
    // Specify helpers which are only registered on this instance.
    helpers: {
        if_equal: function(a, b, opts) {
            if (a == b) {
                return opts.fn(this)
            } else {
                return opts.inverse(this)
            }
        }

    }
});

//The following example sets up an Express app to use 
//.hbs as the file extension for views:
app.engine('.hbs', expressHbs({extname: '.hbs'}));
app.set('view engine', '.hbs'); //with dot
```